# Passing resource through fsockopen() in PHP

Tags: php, fsockopen

I have two servers. Server A has all the databases. How can server B query server A's database and receive the results with `fsockopen()`? 
currently, I can only pass actual text through the socket (i.e. if server A's php code prints out something as in `echo`). How can I pass through the query results (the resource) in this open socket?

Comment: Let me give you this slice of pizza. Wait, I can't transmit it digitally, can I? I'll just send a picture; that's just as good, right?

Comment: More seriously, sending a resource over a network is like sending a local pathname. The other computer may find a file by accessing it, but it won't be the same as the one on your computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using fsockopen is the only way you are able to communicate with Server B's database, serializing the results of the query or encoding them in JSON format and writing them to the socket are possibilities.

Is it not possible to grant read-only access to the mysql server from server A only so you can query directly?  Otherwise a [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) service would be a good alternative to fsockopen.

As stated, you cannot pass the resource over the socket as it wouldn't have any meaning on server A anyway.  If you tried to pass it over the socket it would probably return a string (i.e. Resource #1)

Comment: how would i use REST to pass the resource?

Comment: You can't pass the resource by any means; it is only valid from within the php script that it was created in during the lifetime of the script.  You will need to come up with an alternate method for communicating with the database from server A.

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass the [PHP resource type*<sup>­Docs</sup>*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php) via fsockopen, because fwrite/read will convert the data into a (binary) string. See:

> Converting to resource
>
> As resource variables hold special handlers to opened files, database connections, image canvas areas and the like, converting to a resource makes no sense.

Same is true for converting a resource into something else, e.g. a string.

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing? Just allow remote mysql and let the database server do its job.